# Java 7 way to write a file

Tags: stream, java-7

I have managed to read a file by

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(file.toURI()), System.out);
```

How do I write a sequence of characters to a file? I see no effect from

```
Files.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes()), Paths.get(file.getName()))
```

and it looks ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have succeeded this way

```
Files.write(Paths.get(file.getName()), content.getBytes());
```