# Not writing to text file

Tags: java, file, text, file-io

I currently am having problems writing to the text file in my code, the entirety of the program is hit and everything will print out to the console. no errors. But the file is empty. Any suggestions?

```
public textFiles(String filePath)
{
File file = new File(filePath);

try{
    fstream = new FileWriter(filePath,true);
}
catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
     out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                System.out.println("try");

        addToText("WOOOOHOOO");
          System.out.println(file.exists());


}
public void addToText(String Line)
{
    try {
        out.write(Line);
        out.newLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("writing Error");
    }
    System.out.println("SHOULDA F****** WORKED");
}
```

Comment: Are you closing the writer?

Comment: You are not closing the writer and your code is incomplete and has errors.

Comment: Write inside the try clause. It makes no sense to write in case of create exception. Also, there is [a simpler way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19932828/1083704): `Files.write(Paths.get(file.getName()), content.getBytes());`.

Comment: I appreciate the comments. my code has no errors trojan. It turns out it was because i did not close the writer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're never closing the stream, and so probably never flushing the stream either - the text essentially gets cached when you print it out, and gets flushed to the file in chunks (usually chunks that are much bigger than what you're writing, hence the lack of output.)

Make sure you close the stream when you're done (`fstream.close();`), and it should work fine (the stream will automatically flush to clear any output when it's closed).

Answer (score -1):

Try this code to write a .txt file in any drive.

```
                  try
                  {
                  String ss="html file write in java";
                  File file= new File("F:\\inputfile\\aa.txt");
                  FileWriter fwhn= new FileWriter(file);
                  fwhn.write(ss);
                  fwhn.flush();
                  }
                  catch(Exception ex)
                  {

                  }
```

Comment: While this code flushes, it catches all exceptions (not just IOException), does nothing with the result and still doesn't close the stream... bad practice to say the least!

Comment: This code is simply to write a .txt file in any drive of computer