# How to store textField data in a file?

Tags: java, arraylist, jtextfield

I'm creating a browser and on the browser I have a textField for the urls. I want to be able to store those URLs in an arraylist in a url.txt. If the actionlistner or the hyperlinkListener is called then the addURL() method is called and the text that's in the textField on the browser should be add to the url.txt file.

```
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class storeURL extends browser{
 private Formatter x;

 public storeURL (){
     if(actionState == true || hyperlinkState == true){
         addURL(field);
     }
 }

 public void openFile(){
     try{
         x = new Formatter("urls.txt"); //if file doesn't exist it will creates a file called urls.txt
     }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("You have an error.");
     }
 }

 public void addURL(TextField url){

     x.format("%s", url);

 }

 public void closeFile(){
     x.close(); // closes the file
 }

public void addURL() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: You do it the same way you save a string (e.g. this way, http://stackoverflow.com/a/19932828/1083704). If you do not understand this, you should stay away from programming.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `getText` to retrieve the text from your `TextField`:

```
x.format("%s", url.getText())
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to extract the text from the text field. In your example `url` is the object of type `TextField`. Call its `getText` method to get the contents of the text field. That will be a `String`.

So do it like this:

```
x.format("%s\n", url.getText());
```

Assuming that you are storing a new url on a different line. Otherwise you can use your own seperator.